# Sending data to TCPServer more than one time

Tags: ruby, tcp, tcpserver, tcpsocket

I'm new to ruby and I'm trying to make a client to connect to a TCPServer, and it seems that in order to do so I have to call the method close_write every time I finish sending data one way, to let the client/server know that the other end is finished sending data. Whenever I do that then Im not able to write info to the server or client again because the socket is not opened for writing anymore.
This is my code:

**client.rb**

require "socket"

socket = TCPSocket.open("localhost", 6666)

```
loop do
  input = gets.chomp
  socket.puts input # Send data to server
  socket.close_write
  while(line = socket.gets)
    puts line
  end # Print sever response
  break if input=="EXIT"
end
socket.close
```

**server.rb**

```
require "socket"

server = TCPServer.new 6666
data = Hash.new { |hash, key| hash[key] = {} }

WAITING_SET_VALUE = "1"
WAITING_NEW_COMMAND = "0"

loop do

  Thread.start(server.accept) do |session|
    thread_status ||= WAITING_NEW_COMMAND
    ....

    puts "Entering If..."
    if(thread_status == WAITING_NEW_COMMAND) #Check thread status
      puts "thread_status == WAITING_NEW_COMMAND"
      puts "CHECKING COMMAND.."
      case line.strip
      when /^set \w* \w* \d{1,7} \d{1,7}$/
        puts "COMMAND SET"
        thread_status = WAITING_SET_VALUE
        lineArr = line.strip.split(" ")
        varName = lineArr[1]
        flag = lineArr[2]
        ttl = lineArr[3]
        size = lineArr[4]
        puts "END SET EXECUTION"
        session.write "Executed"
        session.close_write
      ...
```

Is there a way to open the socket for writing again, or a better way to do this back and forth connection between server and client without losing context? Thanks!

Comment: TCP is a continuous stream of bytes. To send data in a message-wise manner, the server needs a way to figure out where one message ends and the next one starts. Common approaches are to use a unique delimiter between the messages or to prefix each message by its length.

Comment: And how can I make the client.rb file know when the server finished sending data back?

Comment: I realized that the server is sending to the client "Data\\n", so now the thing is how do I detect or check in that while loop with gets, that the line has \\n?

Comment: If _newline_ is your delimiter and the server’s reply is just one line, you can replace your `while` loop with a single `gets`. (it reads until it encounters a newline and then return that line)

Comment: Is there a way to keep the while loop but tell the gets function to stop when it encounters the \\n?

Comment: `gets` effectively _is_ a loop – it reads bytes from the stream until it finds a newline and then stops. Putting it inside a `while` loop doesn’t make much sense if you only want to read one line.

Comment: If you want a loop, you can put your client code in a thread so it can read/write without having to call close until the user decides to quit the client. As far as Stefan said, you should look into how people design protocols. A protocol is just some standard you must follow for sending/receiving the data. A simple one just does single lines, and maybe "COUNT 3" to tell you to read the next 3 lines. For example, CLIENT:`LIST MESSAGES` -> SERVER:`COUNT 3\nmsg1\nmsg2\nmsg3\n`

Comment: Is not that I want a loop, is that there are some use cases that Im gonna need to read more than one line from the server, like Im gonna have multiple "puts" server side, and one "gets" from the client is not enough. But for some reason, when I try to read multiple lines in the while loop the gets never recognizes when the server is done sending data

Comment: Your server.rb is using write(), while your client is using socket.gets(). gets() doesn't stop until it gets a newline. In your server, do puts() instead. But even then, it might continue the while loop. It's best not to design a protocol relying on the connection terminating. Instead you design it based on either a termination keyword `socket.gets() == 'END'` or just based on newlines and relying on `COUNT 3` or something similar as I said in the previous comment. Hope this helps.

Comment: Yeah that sure helped, I finally got it working now by doing gets("\0") on the client, and  doing puts("\0") on the server when I want to finish the transfer thank you very much!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When designing a client-server protocol, you have to decide:

- How a client knows when a response has more lines/data.
- How a client knows when a response is complete.
- How a client knows when a response is invalid/valid.
- How a client knows when there was some type of server error.

A simple approach is for the server to return a response with the number of lines (as in the code below). However, instead, you could use `END` or something so that the client knows when there is no more data to read. I would **strongly** suggest looking into tutorials about Protocols.

Save the below into a file called `client_server.rb`. First, run the server with `ruby ./client_server.rb s` and then in a separate terminal run the client with `ruby ./client_server.rb c`. Next, type in `list` over and over to see the different responses. I added `list` so that you don't have to type in `set w w 1 1` over and over for testing purposes. Check it out and let me know if you have any questions.

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

require 'socket'


# Use:
#   First, run the server:  ruby ./client_server.rb s
#   Then, run the client:   ruby ./client_server.rb c

# Use "netcat localhost 6666" on the command line to test
# without implementing a client.


# Returns false to close this client socket.
# Returns true to continue reading from this client socket.
def handle_client(client_id, client_socket, command)

  # TODO: Define some type of client-server Protocol here.
  case command
  when /^set \w* \w* \d{1,7} \d{1,7}$/
    puts "Running command for client #{client_id}: #{command}"

    # This is just for testing purposes.
    case rand(3)
    when 0
      client_socket.puts 'lines 0'
    when 1
      client_socket.puts 'lines 3'
      client_socket.puts 'This is line 1.'
      client_socket.puts 'This is line 2.'
      client_socket.puts 'This is line 3.'
    when 2
      client_socket.puts 'The set command returned an error.'
    end
  when 'list'
    puts "Responding to client #{client_id} with list of messages."

    # This is just for testing purposes.
    case rand(3)
    when 0
      client_socket.puts 'messages 0'
    when 1
      client_socket.puts 'messages 2'
      client_socket.puts 'This is message 1.'
      client_socket.puts 'This is message 2.'
    when 2
      client_socket.puts 'Unable to retrieve messages due to error.'
    end
  when 'bye'
    puts "Killing client #{client_id}."

    return false # Disconnect and kill the thread.
  else
    client_socket.puts "[ERROR] Invalid command: #{command}"
  end

  client_socket.flush # Flush all output just in case.

  true # Continue connection.
end


case ARGV[0].to_s.downcase
when 's' # server
  TCPServer.open(6666) do |server_socket|
    global_client_id = 1

    loop do
      Thread.start(global_client_id, server_socket.accept) do |client_id, client_socket|
        puts "Accepting new client #{client_id}."

        loop do
          command = client_socket.gets

          if command.nil?
            puts "Client #{client_id} disconnected manually."
            break
          end

          command = command.strip
          keep_alive = handle_client(client_id, client_socket, command)

          break unless keep_alive
        end

        client_socket.close
      end

      global_client_id += 1
    end
  end
when 'c' # client
  TCPSocket.open('localhost', 6666) do |socket|
    puts '[Commands]'
    puts 'set <word> <word> <num> <num>    Run set command.'
    puts 'list                             Get list of messages.'
    puts 'exit, bye                        Exit the client.'
    puts

    loop do
      print '> '
      input = $stdin.gets.strip

      # TODO: Define some type of client-server Protocol here.
      case input
      when /EXIT|BYE/i
        socket.puts 'bye'
        socket.flush
        break
      when /\Aset .+\z/
        socket.puts input
        socket.flush

        response = socket.gets

        if response.nil?
          puts 'Server is not running anymore! Disconnecting.'
          break
        end

        response = response.strip
        match_data = response.match(/\Alines (?<lines>\d+)\z/)

        if match_data
          line_count = match_data[:lines].to_i

          puts "Received #{line_count} lines from server."

          1.upto(line_count) do |i|
            line = socket.gets

            puts ">> Resp[#{i}] #{line}"
          end
        else
          # Can check for "response == 'ERROR'" or something.
          puts "Server error or invalid response from server: #{response}"
        end
      when 'list'
        socket.puts input
        socket.flush

        response = socket.gets

        if response.nil?
          puts 'Server is not running anymore! Disconnecting.'
          break
        end

        response = response.strip
        match_data = response.match(/\Amessages (?<messages>\d+)\z/)

        if match_data
          message_count = match_data[:messages].to_i

          puts "Received #{message_count} messages from server."

          1.upto(message_count) do |i|
            line = socket.gets

            puts ">> Resp[#{i}] #{line}"
          end
        else
          # Can check for "response == 'ERROR'" or something.
          puts "Server error or invalid response from server: #{response}"
        end
      else
        puts "Invalid command: #{input}"
      end
    end
  end
else
  puts "Pass in 'c' for client or 's' for server."
end
```

Comment: Awesome, I really appreciate that you took the time to teach me this.
It seems I got it working now thanks to this answer and your previous one.
Thank you!!